# Access local storage value in another React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a login component which makes an API call with email and password to Ruby API and sets the `isLoggedIn = true` if the credentials are correct. When this is true, the navbar shows "logout" link and shows signin/signout when `false`. However, the issue is that it only works fine when page is not reloaded since I am not storing the session anywhere.

I am trying to set login state in local storage when the login is successful. It works fine in the login component, but doesn't when I try to read the local storage value in the other component. I assume this is because I am not storing it in shared state. Is it possible to store the value in state?

Login.js

```
        axios
        .post(apiUrl, {
          user: {
            email: email,
            password: password,
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          if ((response.statusText = "ok")) {
            setLoginStatus({ props.loginState.isLoggedIn: true });
           
           localStorage.setItem('props.loginState.isLoggedIn', true);
            console.log(response)
            history.push("/");
          }
        })
```

App.js

```
let data = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    user: {},
    setSession:null
  };

  const [loginState, setLoginStatus] = useState(data);
  const rememberMe = localStorage.getItem('loginState.isLoggedIn')
```

When I use console log the below either in App.js or Nav.js the value is `null` always.

localStorage.getItem('props.loginState.isLoggedIn');

Comment: @TusharShahi that's what I did if you see in App.js

Comment: Did you do this : const rememberMe = localStorage.getItem('props.loginState.isLoggedIn'); in App.js?

Comment: @TusharShahi Why would you use props in parent component?

Comment: Because the localStorage items as are saved as key value pairs.  This is a string - 'props.loginState.isLoggedIn'. It could have been 'xaxax' or 'manana'. Since you saved it with that key name it can only be accessed with that key name.

Comment: Sure. Posting an answer to complete this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The localStorage items as are saved as key value pairs. This is a string `'props.loginState.isLoggedIn'`, and will be access the same way from any component. Since you saved it with that key name it can only be accessed with that key name from any component.